# Dice Poker Score Algorithm?

Tags: java

Trying to get these algorithms to evaluate an array filled with five randomly chosen integers ranging from 1-6. Unfortunately, it will only return the high card and one pair options. How do I access the higher scores when I roll a two pair, three of a kind, etc.?

```
private static int[] getCounts(int[] dice) {

    int[] counts = new int[6];
    String resValue = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < dice.length; i++) {
        if (dice[i] == 1) {
            counts[0]++;
        } else if (dice[i] == 2) {
            counts[1]++;
        } else if (dice[i] == 3) {
            counts[2]++;
        } else if (dice[i] == 4) {
            counts[3]++;
        } else if (dice[i] == 5) {
            counts[4]++;
        } else if (dice[i] == 6) {
            counts[5]++;
        }
    }
    return counts;
}

private static String getResult(int[] dice) {
    int[] counts = getCounts(dice);
    String resValue = " ";

    for (int i = 0; i < counts.length; i++) {
        if (counts[i] == 5) {
            resValue = "Five of a kind ";
        } else if (counts[i] == 4) {
            resValue = "Four of a kind ";
        } else if (counts[i] == 3) {
            for (int j = 0; j < counts.length; j++) {
                if (counts[j] == 2) {
                    resValue = "Full House ";
                }
            }
            resValue = "Three of a Kind ";
        } else if (counts[i] == 2) {
            for (int j = 0; j < counts.length; j++) {
                if (counts[j] == 2) {
                    resValue = "Two Pairs ";
                }
            }
            resValue = "One Pair ";
        } else {
            resValue = "Highest Card ";
        }
    }
    return resValue;
}
```

Comment: don't know solution for your problem..but this link will be use full for you..
http://probabilityandstats.wordpress.com/2010/04/28/the-game-of-poker-dice-and-the-multinomial-theorem/

Comment: You should definitely use `counts[dice[i] - 1]++` instead of having 6 if-else statements.

Answer (score 0):

Your if else has to wide range. The last else executes even if we found higher resValue before. Either add check, to see if new resValue is higher, or add break at the end of each clause.

EDIT: here, it worked for me:

```
private static int[] getCounts(int[] dice) {
        int[] counts = new int[6];
        String resValue = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < dice.length; i++) {
            if (dice[i] == 1) {
                counts[0]++;
            } else if (dice[i] == 2) {
                counts[1]++;
            } else if (dice[i] == 3) {
                counts[2]++;
            } else if (dice[i] == 4) {
                counts[3]++;
            } else if (dice[i] == 5) {
                counts[4]++;
            } else if (dice[i] == 6) {
                counts[5]++;
            }
        }
        return counts;
    }

    private static String getResult(int[] dice) {
        int[] counts = getCounts(dice);
        String resValue = " ";

        for (int i = 0; i < counts.length; i++) {
            if (counts[i] == 5) {
                resValue = "Five of a kind ";
                break;
            } else if (counts[i] == 4) {
                resValue = "Four of a kind "; break;
            } else if (counts[i] == 3) {
                resValue = "Three of a Kind ";
                for (int j = 0; j < counts.length; j++) {
                    if (counts[j]==2) {
                        resValue = "Full House "; break;
                    }
                }
                break;
            } else if (counts[i] == 2) {
                 resValue = "One Pair ";
                for (int j = 0; j < counts.length; j++) {
                    if (counts[j] == 2) {
                        resValue = "Two Pairs "; break;
                    }
                }
               break;
            } else {
                resValue = "Highest Card ";
            }
        }
        return resValue;
    }
```